# Unity VideoPlayer on Android builds : black screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video

Working on a Unity 3D Android app.

I'm playing videos on a Skybox.

It works well on half the Android devices I tested, the other half render a black screen and I'm supposing the VideoPlayer doesnt even start since I'm not hearing the sound of the video.

It seems pretty random on what devices it works or not. Cant seem to rank them by Android version. It works on some phones and on some tablets. The only common thing is that it doesnt work on Samsung devices.

The logs show no errors.
I tried modifying Graphics API.

I'm on Unity 2018.1.3

Thank you !!

Comment: Do you have SDK tools updated? Platform-tools LLDB and NDK?

Comment: SDK tools are up to date yes. I'm not using LLDB and NDK (Unity build).
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices have a resolution limitation.
4K videos was too much.